# How do I disable Apport from including a core dump?

Tags: openjdk, apport

Intro: apport is a python applicaton running on ubuntu which automates bug reporting.  In case of a crash it determines which application crashed, and auto generates a detailed report on the crash, including various details on the environment/system in which the crash occurred.

Recently I had a few crashes (signal 5: Trace/breakpoint trap) of the Java run-time ( executable:
 `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64_jre/bin/java` ) while running a (non Ubuntu) financial application.

I like to help improve Ubuntu by emailing the detailed report, but one thing prevents me from doing so.  The report includes a full core dump of the application which may have some serious privacy implications.

The question is how can I allow the report (so it can help developers fix the crash in java itself), but disable the core-file shipping with it.

Note that I don't want to disable core file generation altogether.  I just want to prevent apport from adding it to the report.

Comment: this means, for ex., if gedit crashes, that file's data opened on it will be dumped and sent? :O

Answer (score 0):

### Create a Setting / Core Dump is usually the useful part of a bug report

At the moment, I do not believe that apport supports that. However, you could certainly check out apport on Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/apport, create a setting to not include the core dump (although that is mainly the useful part of a bug report), and then compile and install it yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  I followed the link but couldn't find the 'setting' you're referring to.  Could you edit the answer to be more detailed on how to get there, e.g. which tab/link to follow, and what to do?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, but I kinda meant that you could check out the code from launchpad, code in an option to not include core dumps, and then compile it yourself, build a package, and install it in place of the system installed apport. If you do end up doing this, please submit the changes back to launchpad. If you can't code it in, a feature request can be submitted to apport on launchpad. Don't hesitate to ask for clarification, it's always a pleasure.